# Open a protected pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf, passwords

I write a pdf cracking and found the password of the protected pdf file. I want to write a program in Python that can display that pdf file on the screen without password.I use the PyPDF library.
I know how to open a file without the password, but can't figure out the protected one.Any idea? Thanks

```
filePath = raw_input()
password = 'abc'
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
       subprocess.call(["xdg-open", filePath])
```

Answer (score 17):

The approach shown by KL84 basically works, but the code is not correct (it writes the output file for each page). A cleaned up version is here:

https://gist.github.com/bzamecnik/1abb64affb21322256f1c4ebbb59a364

```
# Decrypt password-protected PDF in Python.
# 
# Requirements:
# pip install PyPDF2

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def decrypt_pdf(input_path, output_path, password):
  with open(input_path, 'rb') as input_file, \
    open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
    reader = PdfFileReader(input_file)
    reader.decrypt(password)

    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
      writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))

    writer.write(output_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # example usage:
  decrypt_pdf('encrypted.pdf', 'decrypted.pdf', 'secret_password')
```

Comment: what's decrypted.pdf over here?

Comment: That's `output_path`, the name of the out file to be written.

Comment: just want to say that I have to remove password argument and `reader.decrypt(password)` part to make it work.

Comment: How comes that? Was your PDF really encrypted? This is the main point of the script.

Comment: I get an error on the line `reader.decrypt(password)`. `only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported`. I think it is related to how my pdf is encrypted.

Answer (score 11):

You should use [pikepdf](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf) library nowadays instead:

```
import pikepdf

with pikepdf.open("input.pdf", password="abc") as pdf:
    num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
    print("Total pages:", num_pages)
```

`PyPDF2` doesn't support many encryption algorithms, `pikepdf` seems to solve them, it supports most of password protected methods, and also documented and actively maintained.

Comment: Excellent!.. you are correct, PyPDF2 won't decrypt some encryption algorithms

Answer (score 3):

You can use pdfplumber library. Super easy to use and reads machine written pdf files seamlessly, better than any other library i have used.

```
import pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open(r'D:\examplepdf.pdf' , password = 'abc') as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    print(first_page.extract_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer for this question. Basically, the PyPDF2 library needs to install and use in order to get this idea working.

```
#When you have the password = abc you have to call the function decrypt in PyPDF to decrypt the pdf file
filePath = raw_input("Enter pdf file path: ")
f = PdfFileReader(file(filePath, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
f.decrypt ('abc')

# Copy the pages in the encrypted pdf to unencrypted pdf with name noPassPDF.pdf
for pageNumber in range (0, f.getNumPages()):
   output.addPage(f.getPage(pageNumber))
   # write "output" to noPassPDF.pdf
   outputStream = file("noPassPDF.pdf", "wb")
   output.write(outputStream)
   outputStream.close()

#Open the file now
   if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):#open in MAC OX
       subprocess.call(["open", "noPassPDF.pdf"])
```

Comment: "raise NotImplementedError("only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported")" error.

Answer (score 1):

Updated version of Bohumir Zamecnik's Code. for PyPDF 3.0.0 and Above

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def decrypt_pdf(input_path, output_path, password):
  with open(input_path, 'rb') as input_file, \
    open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
    reader = PdfReader(input_file)
    reader.decrypt(password)

    writer = PdfWriter()

    for i in range(len(reader.pages)):
      writer.add_page(reader.pages[i])

    writer.write(output_file)

decrypt_pdf('encrypr.pdf', 'decrypted.pdf', 'password')
```