# How Open PASSWORD PROTECTED pdf file using textract

Tags: python, pdf

I'm working on pdf's and have created full project but now facing one problem that how to parse through  contents of Password Protected PDF files (I know that password).

Comment: Can try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130032/open-a-protected-pdf-file-in-python

Comment: @bunbun Those don't use textract.

Comment: you dont need to use textract for decryption...

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/pull/137

Comment: Try `extract(filename, '−upw password')`