# How to open password protected pdf- document?

Tags: python, pdf

Kubuntu 21.10, Python 3.9.5

I use this code:

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open(file_name) #ERROR!

#idata = open(file_name, "rb").read()  # read the PDF into memory
#ibuffer = BytesIO(idata)  # convert to stream
#doc = fitz.Document(stream=ibuffer, filetype='pdf') #ERROR!

doc.authenticate(my_password)
```

and I always get an error:
*RuntimeError: encryption dictionary missing owner password*

How to open my pdf- file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130032/open-a-protected-pdf-file-in-python

Comment: In a line: value = reader.decrypt(my_password) I get this error: NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported

Comment: Yes, my file "ask for a password in a PDF reader like a browser".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can crack the .pdf file password:

Firstly: pip3 install pikepdf tqdm

```
import pikepdf
from tqdm import tqdm

# load password list
passwords = [ line.strip() for line in open("wordlist.txt") ]

# iterate over passwords
for password in tqdm(passwords, "Decrypting PDF"):
    try:
        # open PDF file
        with pikepdf.open("foo-protected.pdf", password=password) as pdf:
            # Password decrypted successfully, break out of the loop
            print("[+] Password found:", password)
            break
    except pikepdf._qpdf.PasswordError as e:
        # wrong password, just continue in the loop
        continue
```

Comment: When the line with pikepdf.open() is executed I get following error: pikepdf._qpdf.PdfError: /home/denis/Downloads/important_file.pdf (encryption dictionary, offset 1826): incorrect length for /O and/or /U in encryption dictionary