# Extract the First Page of a Signed (encrypted) PDF Using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to automate a long manual workflow for my work using Python. I need to get the first page of 10 different PDFs,  and combine them together into one PDF. However, these PDFs are digitally signed using Adobe Sign, so they are 'encryted.'

I tried to use PyPDF2 package but it cannot split encrypted PDFs. Current the manual workaround is to print the first page of each PDF to PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF, as shown below. I don't know how to use the python.os to use Microsoft Print and print the only first page of each encrypted PDF...

***EDIT: The PDFs are 'encrypted' but does not require a password to open or print. And PDFs do prevent people to edit them because they are 'encrypted.' Note I put quotes around 'encrypted' because they are encrypted only in some ways.. The software I used is Adobe Acrobat Professional.***

[image]

Your guidance and insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software you're using, but a digital signature is not encryption, they are different things.  If something is encrypted, you will need the corresponding digital key in order to decrypt the data.  This key will be private to the party intended to receive the private data.  If something is signed, that gives assurance that a certain party has validated a piece of data (but the data and the signature could still be un-encrypted).

Comment: Here are a answer about how to open a pdf with password https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130032/open-a-protected-pdf-file-in-python

Comment: @Jack *"I'm not familiar with the software you're using, but a digital signature is not encryption, they are different things"* - this is technically true. But the Adobe Sign Service the op deals with (in contrast to local Adobe Acrobat signing) appears to have the quirk of creating results which are *not only signed but also encrypted*. For encryption the default user password is used, so opening the file is no issue, encryption is only applied to apply access restrictions.

Comment: @mkl Exactly you are right. I'm using Adobe Acrobat. The PDFs are digitally signed by multiple signatories. It's 'encrypted' but does not require password to open it. However, it obscures PyPDF2 to split it because it's still 'encrypted' in some way.

Comment: *"It's 'encrypted' but does not require password to open it."* - It's encrypted using the _default password_. When dealing with an encrypted PDF, PDF viewers first try to decrypt using the default password. If that works, they don't ask you for a password at all.

Comment: @mkl the tricky part is that I am not the one who created those PDFs so I don't know the default password... The only workaround now is to print this PDF to PDF (weird method Ikr)

Comment: The _default password_ is the empty string.