# Getting this error: RuntimeError: Proxy error(FileNotFoundException): Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\stuff\tests\pythonlearn.pdf'

Tags: python, pdf

```
import os
import aspose.words as aw  


rootdir = 'C:/Users/user/stuff/tests'


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        a = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        doc = aw.Document(a)
        doc.save("utput.docx")
        doc = aw.Document("Output.docx")
        doc.save("output.pdf")
```

This is my program.

I am trying to run python through a folder containing pdf files, and decrypt them one by one by converting it to word, and then to pdf. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `os.walk`. use `os.listdir(rootdir)` instead. Please note that the saved file and the used file have the same name.

Example:

```
import os
import aspose.words as aw 

root = "C:/Users/user/stuff/tests"
for item in os.listdir(root):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
        doc = aw.Document(item)
        doc.save("Output.docx")
        doc = aw.Document("Output.docx")
        doc.save("output.pdf")
```

**[EDIT]**

above code cant find other folders so i decide to use `glob` to find all folders

Here:

```
import os 
import aspose.words as aw
import glob
# Set base directory  
os.chdir(os.path.join("C:/Users/user/stuff/tests"))
# Geting all pdf files in list
pdf_files = glob.glob("*.pdf")
for files in pdf_files: 
        doc = aw.Document(files) 
        doc.save("Output.docx") 
        doc = aw.Document("Output.docx") 
        doc.save("output.pdf")
```

**[EDIT-2]**

First take all .pdf files in one list :

```
pdf_files = glob.glob("*.pdf")
other_pdf_files = glob.glob('*/*.pdf')
all_pdf_files=(*pdf_files,*other_pdf_files)
```

Secondly, you need to use `PyPDF2`  to get rid of password.
Get unencrypted pdfs by sending all pdf files into `decrypt_pdf` (don't forget to specify the password). For example: (More detail [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-encrypt-a-pdf-using-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130032/open-a-protected-pdf-file-in-python))

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def decrypt_pdf(input_path, output_path, password):
  with open(input_path, 'rb') as input_file, \
    open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
    reader = PdfFileReader(input_file)
    reader.decrypt(password)

    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
      writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))

    writer.write(output_file)
```

You can run other parts in the same way.

```
for files in all_pdf_files:  
        doc = aw.Document(files)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with this. But it is only processing the Py file inside. I have many pdfs inside, and this is skipping them. Any idea why?  I have changed the program a bit, and now it is:        import os
import aspose.words as aw  


rootdir = 'C:/Users/user/stuff/tests'


for files in os.listdir(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        doc = aw.Document(file)
        doc.save("Output.docx")
        doc = aw.Document("Output.docx")
        doc.save("output.pdf")

Comment: The error which I am now getting is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\stuff\tests\ex1.py", line 10, in <module>
    doc = aw.Document(file)
RuntimeError: Proxy error(UnauthorizedAccessException): Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\stuff\tests\1' is denied.

Comment: Edited. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If it would have been a single pdf file that would have worked. But I have sub-folders in tests, each containing a pdf file. I want to open all those folders individually and carry out the decryption

Comment: ```import os 
from pdf2docx import parse
import glob
# Set base directory  

rootdir = 'C:/Users/user/stuff/tests'
# Geting all pdf files in list
for files in os.listdir(rootdir):
    pdf_files = glob.glob("*.pdf")
    for pdf_files in files: 
        docx_file = 'sample.docx'
        parse(pdf_files, docx_file) ```

Comment: I updated the code with the input from @heywtu.  But while I run it I am getting a FileNotFoundError

Comment: Edited. I hope this time no problems show.